# Helm package in Go

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm

I'm attempting to use the helm package in Go to delete releases, using a specific namespace causes a panic exit with the following message (got it from journalctl) *"service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT"*

I'm able to list releases from a namespace using the following code:

```
err := actionConfig.Init(settings.RESTClientGetter(), "my-namespace", os.Getenv("HELM_DRIVER"), nil)

releaseList := action.NewList(actionConfig)
releases, err := releaseList.Run()
```

And I can see all the releases in that namespace. But when using the same config to initialize the Uninstall:

```
    deleter := action.NewUninstall(actionConfig)
    _, err := deleter.Run("my-release-name")
```

It is when I get the panic in the .Run()

If I don't specify the namespace and instead I use the config

```
actionConfig.Init(settings.RESTClientGetter(), settings.Namespace(), os.Getenv("HELM_DRIVER"), nil)
```

It doesn't cause the panic but it will not find the release name in the default namespace.

What can I do to properly delete it from the right namespace?

---

Aditionally, managed to debug the following:

```
level":"DEBUG","msg":"Debug","format":"Ignoring delete failure for %q %s: %v","v":["my-release-name",{"Group":"networking.k8s.io","Version":"v1","Kind":"Ingress"},{"ErrStatus":{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"ingresses.networking.k8s.io \"my-release-name\" not found","reason":"NotFound","details":{"name":"my-release-name","group":"networking.k8s.io","kind":"ingresses"},"code":404}}]}
```

This Debug output replaced the panic exit when using the same code but activating the flag:

```
deleter.IgnoreNotFound = true
```

Comment: What is the panic?  Do you actually get a panic (which is probably a bug in the Helm library) or a non-nil `err`?

Comment: After more debugging, I found that the helm library thrown the panic when the release to delete was not being found. After using the flag "deleter.IgnoreNotFound = true" what I see is that it never finds the release or even use the namespace even if you specifies it.

(I updated the question with this info too :) )